# Getting 401 Authorization Required from client Filebeat in ELK ElasticSearch Logstash Kibana)

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I'm trying to setup my first **ELK** environment on RHEL7 using [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-centos-7#connect-to-kibana),

I installed all required components (Nginx,logstash,kibana,elasticsearch),

I also installed filebeat on my client machine that I'm trying to pull the logs from, But when checking the installation I get 401:

```
[root@myd-vm666 beats-dashboards-1.1.0]# curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_search?pretty'
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

in my filebeat configuration I stated the logstash host and the certificate location as follows:

```
#================================ Outputs =====================================

# Configure what outputs to use when sending the data collected by the beat.
# Multiple outputs may be used.

#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
#output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  #hosts: ["16.XX.XXX.XXX:9200"]

  # Optional protocol and basic auth credentials.
  #protocol: "https"
  #username: "elastic"
  #password: "changeme"

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["16.XX.XXX.XXX:5044"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/root/ca.pem"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"

  tls:
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  certificate_authorities: "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
```

I verified that The **logstash-forwarder.crt** is in the right place.
And on my server, I have this configuration, /etc/logstash/conf.d/02-beats-input.conf

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
}
```

What am I missing? is there another key/certificate I need to place on the client?

Answer (score 0):

If you are approaching AWS Elasticsearch with username/password security as
then and version of both are compatible then

In Aws, while configuring your Elasticsearch service configure it for whitelisting of IP instead of Master User.
or
Configure FileBeat–> Logstash–>Elasticsearch with master username/password also it will work.
Reference: https://learningsubway.com/filebeat-401-unauthorized-error-with-aws-elasticsearch/